# sed search and replace number with another on specific line

Tags: sed

I would like to replace in multiple dump files (*.sql):

```
`this_pattern` varchar(255)
```

by

```
`this_pattern` varchar(100)
```

i.e. only when "this_pattern" is present on the line.

I tried simple with:

```
echo "varchar(255)" | sed -e 's/\(255\)/100/g'
```

but I don't know how to put the `this_pattern` condition.

```
sed "/^`this_pattern`/ s/\(255\)/100/g"
```

did nothing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So `this_pattern` is, including backticks, at the start of line? You should provide 2-3 sample lines of input, of expected output, including cases where no substitution takes place, [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using a *capturing group*  `( )` :

```
$ cat file
`this_pattern` varchar(255)
varchar(255)

$ sed -E '/^`this_pattern`/ s/(varchar)\(255\)/\1(100)/g' file
`this_pattern` varchar(100)
varchar(255)
```

Comment: Thank Gilles, and especially for the add in the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'this_pattern varchar(255)' | sed '/^this_pattern.*/ s/varchar(255)/varchar(100)/g'
```

Without -r switch, sed treats round parens just as characters.

If this_pattern is masked by backticks, like in the original post, it's a bit more complicated, but that doesn't look plausible. However, here we go:

```
echo '`this_pattern` varchar(255)' | sed '/^`this_pattern` .*/ s/varchar(255)/varchar(100)/g'
`this_pattern` varchar(100)
```

Note: There might be variable whitespace between 'pattern' and 'varchar' and 'varchar' and '(' and so on. So you have to be careful about this. Sometimes, it's a one time job, with dozens of lines, sometimes it's a repeated job. Sometimes the input is of generic nature, and expected to always look the same, sometimes it's man made, and may differ from time to time. You have to take that into account, when doing massive updates.

Keeping a copy of the source is often a good idea. Often editors allow using regular expressions, where mass renaming is possible, but they mark the places so you can oversee the changes, which will be made.

Comment: Yes, the backticks are part of the game. They are there for columns of tables to be created from the dumps. Thanks for the help, it works !